# Confusing behavior from computed properties with async Ember models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I ran into some strange behavior trying to build computed properties into my Ember Data model. Here's what my `.coffee` file looks like:

```
LineItemModel = DS.Model.extend
  quantity: attr 'number'
  length: attr 'number'
  product: DS.belongsTo 'product', async: true
  priceAdjust: attr 'number', defaultValue: 0

  weight: (->
    return this.get('product.weight') * length
  ).property('product')

  # Get MLF price
  price: (->
    # Adjust if percentage is specified
    adjust = (mlf, adjustment) ->
      return mlf unless adjustment
      mlf += Math.ceil(mlf * adjustment / 100)

    prices = this.get('product').get 'prices'
    level = this.get('quote').get 'level'
    price = prices.filterBy 'level', level
    return if price[0] then adjust( price[0], this.get('priceAdjust') ) else 0
  ).property('product', 'product.@each.prices', 'quote.level', 'priceAdjust')
```

My problem is that in my `weight` method `this.get('product.weight')` always returns undefined. I've done some testing and anything other than `this.get('product.id')` returns undefined. To make thing even more confusing, this works

`Ember.computed.alias('product.weight')`

and this from with the `price` method

```
  # Get MLF price
  price: (->
     console.log this.get('product.weight')
     ...
```

This is the product model for reference:

```
ProductModel = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  weight: attr 'number'
  prices: DS.hasMany 'price', async: true
```

I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if this is a bug. This is a cli app `v0.1.15`

Comment: Could you clarify why a `product_id` property would be connected in a 1-1 relationship with a `product` type? The way that the `price` computed property refers to `product_id` with an `@each` signifies to me that it's a collection of items. Preliminarily, my guess is that your `weight` computed property should be looking at `product_id.@each.weight`. Or you should be doing a reduce function on that value.

Comment: I refactored the code for a little clarity but basically our API is still in development and I haven't built any serializers yet. Price is actually another model because we have a lot of variable pricing per each product but weight is always a set `int` value. What throws me off the most is that I can get the weight value from inside the price method, just not from inside the weight method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I can tell, the problem is related to promises as whether or not they're resolved. Here's what I came up with so far:

`weight: Ember.computed.alias 'product.weight'`

Computed property easily takes care of handling the promise relationship business

```
# Lbs / Ft
lbs: (->
  return this.get('weight') * this.get('length')    
).property('weight', 'length')
```

Now I know I have some value for weight and I can do my calculation with it. I'm still not sure why I didn't seem to need this in the `price` method but this seems like the "Ember" way to do things. I'd love some feedback if this can be improved.